# UIActionSheet behaving weirdly in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

I have the following view hierarchy

```
MMDrawerViewController
```

--`UINavigationController` (`CenterViewController`)

-----`UITableViewController` (RootViewController for `UINavigationViewController`)

---------`UIToolbar` with 1 `barButtonItem`

--`UIViewController` (`LeftSideViewController`)

Now when the button item is selected, a `UIActionSheet` is shown. This works perfectly fine when I just run the app and select the `barButtonItem`. But if I select another option, which present modals another view controller followed by dismissing the view controller, now if I select the `barButtonItem`, the background of the `UIActionSheet` is misplaced.

Kindly check the attached image.
[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update**
This is how I show the UIActionSheet

```
UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Upload", @"Create Folder", @"Create File", nil];
[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
[actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

Comment: Have you checked the view from which you are presenting the UIActionSheet.

Comment: kindly check the updated problem.

Comment: instead of presenting it from toolbar please once try to present it from UIView.

Comment: same result... I have tried all the options available with UIActionSheet